# XQuery: Getting multiple attribute values

Tags: xpath, xquery

So I'm trying to access the country codes of the following, but with no luck:

```
  <river id="river-Rhone" country="F CH">
  <name>Rhone</name>
  <located country="F" />
  <located country="CH"/>
  </river>
```

Is there a way to get them? I tried access them by index but nothing works. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to get /located/@country as output:

**XQUERY:**

```
let $XML := <river id="river-Rhone" country="F CH">
              <name>Rhone</name>
              <located country="F" />
              <located country="CH"/>
             </river>
for $country in $XML//located/@country
return 
 <p>{data($country)}</p>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<p>F</p>
<p>CH</p>
```

Comment: what if I'm trying to access the main tag's attribute 'country'? Because sometimes there are more country codes in the main attribute than that of its children. This is my main question, tbh, but I didn't articulate it enough. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to change XPATH from $XML//located/@country to  $XML/@country to get output <p>F CH</p>

Comment: Yeah, but I want to split them by space. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

so as @Navin Rawat has suggested you can do something like:

```
tokenize($river/@country, '\s+')
```